# How to @Inject into main class - Java - Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework

I'm creating a main class in Play framework. Then I tried to @Inject another DAO object, as below:

```java
public class HistoricalTask { 
    @Inject
    protected static DataDao dataDao = 
    Play.current().injector().instanceOf(DataDao.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<DataObject> rs = dataDao.getData();
    }
}
```

But, it doesn't work. And I got an error:
`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application`

So, Is there any solution to create another main class, using @Inject feature and separate with Play web server?

Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that since your application is still in initialisation process.

If you want to initialise something at the time of application startup consider creating a module and add it to your application.conf file. Here you can register all the beans you want and any specific initialisation that you want to do by binding an eager singleton.

For example:

```
public class DaoHelperModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(DaoService.class).asEagerSingleton();
  }

}
```

Then in application.conf file:

```
play.modules.enabled += "services.producer.DaoHelperModule"
```

You can inject dependencies in the module as well.